# Export Dottrace report to a useable format

Tags: c#, jetbrains-ide, dottrace

I would like to automatize tests based on dottrace reports to ensure that my code is not regressing in terms of performances.
The thing is I can't use dottrace reports because of their format, it would be easier to get an XML file or anything else useable as a report.

Any idea of what I could do?

**EDIT :** in dottrace 2018 you can use this page:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Performance_Profiling__Profiling_Using_the_Command_Line.html

Comment: Having your data stuck in a closed file format is _really_, _REALLY_ sly of JetBrains!